# callback excutes on server side or client-side?

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I'm developing a web application on ASP.NET, .NET 4, DevExpress 10.2. My question is... The Performed callback executed by a Callback control occurs on client-side or server-side?

Example:

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="Link" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClientClick="cbRefresh.PerformCallback(this);">
</asp:LinkButton>
```

Comment: Did you try it and see which one it does? What were the results?

Comment: Check this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.linkbutton.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: manson, the truth is that I don't know how to try it. I read your link Jose, so, as it says it executes on client-side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Client side!

OnClientClick property is for client side javascript code.

Refer this documentation 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.button.onclientclick(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Your question has two answers. Both!

Firstly, the `LinkButton` invokes the `OnClientClick`event, which is a Client-Side event.

So, when the user clicks on the link, you enter the event, where you are calling `cbRefresh.PerformCallback(this)`. I am assuming that `cbRefresh` is a DeveloperExpress `CallbackPanel` which has been asked to invoke the server-side, `CustomCallback` event. Thus the second part is executed on the server-side.

Hope that helps!